# Regex expression that requires a user to input a number as a %

Tags: javascript, string, percentage

Can't figure out how to create a regex expression that requires the user to input a number as a %

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's very simple, it looks like this:

```js
const val1 = "10";
const val2 = "10%";

const checkPercentage = val => /\d+%$/.test(val);

console.log(checkPercentage(val1));
console.log(checkPercentage(val2));
```

**\d+** represents between 1 digit and +

**%$** means that the "%" sign must be at the end of the string.

;)